# asp.net & Knockout : ko.subscribable() - one vm in sitemaster.js (globally) and one vm in mypage.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, master-pages

I'm using the ko.subscribable() functionality, to pass an object from knockout in mypage.js used in mypage.aspx (which inherits from site.master) to knockout in sitemaster.js (site.master.aspx) which is loaded and used in every page in my solution.

The problem is.. when following the recommended structure of using this functionality (see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paxnd6uz/266/)) it states that i have to have one "MasterViewModel" which creates both of the viewmodels, which i find problematic in the scenario where you have two seperate javascript files, either though both are loaded in the destinationpage (mypage.aspx).

**This is the necessary code i cannot figure out how to handle :**

```
var masterVM = (function(){
this.viewModel1 =  new viewModel1(),
this.viewModel2 = new viewModel2();
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM)
```

Here is my code :

**mypage.js**

```
var shouter = new ko.subscribable();

var PhotoModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.photos = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPhoto = ko.observable();
    self.setSelectedPhoto = function(selPhoto) {
        self.selectedPhoto.subscribe(function (selPhoto) {
            shouter.notifySubscribers(selPhoto, "photoToShow");
        });
    }
}

var photosModel = new PhotoModel();
ko.applyBindings(photosModel, document.getElementById("latest-photos"));
```

**sitemaster.js**

```
var PhotoViewModel = function(photosModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.viewPhoto = ko.observable();
    shouter.subscribe(function(selPhoto) {
        self.viewPhoto(selPhoto);
    }, self, "photoToShow");
};

var photoViewModel = new PhotoViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(photoViewModel, document.getElementById("photo-viewer"));
```

Comment: I personally have no problem with using more that one viewmodel on a page. Partularly when the vm may be some what large and complex.

Comment: This is two vm's on two different pages /scriptfiles, and they need to communicate with eachother :)

Comment: In a true master/content page the content page should be able to use anything created on the master page.  So include the site.js in the master but do the binding on the content page.

Comment: a similar situation I handled in typescript modules by sending the value to the parent module (a separate file) by setting a parent variable and then using this parent variable to set the value to a child module's variable(both children were separate module with a separate ts file)....